# Reliable way to get image info from gridview?

Tags: java, android, gridview

Basically, I need a way of getting the id/name/something of the image in the gridview in order to know what the user tapped on.

here is the code of the imageadapter, I got from another tutorial:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6, };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setId(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

This all works fine, and sets the id to the integer of the R.value.
in my onCreate method, I have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                String name = getStringId(v.getId()); //this is a method of else ifs that just gets a string name based on the int id.

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }
```

This also all works fine. The problem that I have, is that the R.values all changed! which means that the original int id no longer points to the right image, and basically you can't do anything with it. So my question, is there a more reliable way of setting the ids of the images? So when I add some new drawable, it doesnt completely mess up everything?

Answer (score 0):

you should use instead:

```
AdapterView<?> .getItemAtPosition(int position)
```

For instance

```
   Integer imageId = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Edit

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Integer imageId = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(int position);
            if (imageId != null) {
                   // process your imageID
             }
            String name = getStringId(v.getId()); //this is a method of else ifs that just gets a string name based on the int id.

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: well this does exactly the same thing... it just returns the R.value. Which means if I add or change any drawable, they will all change.